# all fire and toe

Tags: etymology, idioms, idiom-meaning, phrase-origin

I'm reading the as-told-to memoir, [*No Quittin' Sense*](https://archive.org/details/noquittinsense0000whit/page/156/mode/2up?q=fire+and+tow), of a black man born and raised in East Texas circa 1895. He quotes the expression "all fire and toe".

> After we left, Marthy said "She's all fire and toe, ain't she?"

What does it mean?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some context for the idiom? As someone who's been studying Southern Black English for some years, I'm interested in further tracking this. Often, idiomatic expressions seem mysterious because of pronunciation-- the transcriber simply misunderstood what the interviewee was saying. The closest I've heard is "get up some (or "your") fire and try", as an expression of encouragement.

Comment: Please add a linked reference and the complete sentence.

Comment: First comment links to context. I didn't provide context because I anticipated it would trigger guesses. I appreciate good intentions, but in this case not interested in guesses.  And, yes, there's misundertanding/bad transcription in as-told-to's but I'm pretty sure its not the case here. I googled around and found a few other examples of 'all fire & toe'. Otherwise, I've also been studying SBE for years. Curious to know what you consider the ultimate text. For me, it's ALL GOD"S DANGERS.

Comment: @RustyBrooklyn Which first comment? I don't see any link you've given anywhere in a comment.

Comment: When it comes to the speech of black folks in the South, no text is definitive. Your reference is a good one. Also, the slave narratives recorded by the WPA in the 1930s are invaluable. My schooling began with the neighbor lady who was 113 years old and told me stories of her memories of Reconstruction (or so she claimed). One thing I've learned is that vernacular language is a register where individual creativity is honored, so that one person could alter an idiom slightly to make it more clever. So it's not always possible to find in some reference book every phrase uttered.

Comment: As in the [Canterbury tales](http://www.librarius.com/canttran/wifetale/wifetale083-100.htm).  [fyr and tow](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0013838x.2015.1090739?forwardService=showFullText&tokenAccess=ns5t2bB46aAzNKbG3nnZ&tokenDomain=eprints&doi=10.1080%2F0013838x.2015.1090739&doi=10.1080%2F0013838x.2015.1090739&journalCode=nest20)

Comment: Tow is untwisted plant fibers, often carried and used as kindling. It was produced commercially for caulking from the remains of rope making. It was often mixed with resins and tar. [link boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-boy)

Comment: @JEL Except that I haven't a clue what the Texan meant by the phrase or how it would have gotten to Texas, except I did find one tantalizing reference - [Matthew Henry Bible Commentary, 1710](https://www.christianity.com/bible/commentary.php?com=mh&b=20&c=14), Proverbs 14:29.

Comment: "all fire and tow" with little doubt refers on a literal level to the flame that leaps out when the wick of a candle catches fire before burning down to the point where the wax moderates the flame so that it burns steadily.  So I suspect the figurative meaning is to be found in what it would mean to compare a person to that sudden and short-lived flare of flame.  A gossip, or someone who is insubstantial, i.e. talks nonsense.

Comment: Farther into the narrative, the man mentions a "tow sack", which is the same as a gunny sack. So, a sack made of untwisted plant fibers as Phil Sweet says.

Answer (score 5):

[*OED*](https://oed.com/) reports finding 'toe' as a variant spelling of 'tow' in the 17th and 18th centuries. The two words are also often homophones in both UK and US English.

The 'toe' in "fire and toe" from Marthy's comment in *No Quittin' Sense* is more likely a transcription error based on homophony than a variant spelling of 'tow': *No Quittin' Sense* is the "author's life story, based on tape recordings of his own narrative, and written down in book form by A. M. Holland" (description at [entry](https://archive.org/details/noquittinsense0000whit/page/156/mode/2up?q=fire%20and%20tow) for book on *Internet Archive*).

> tow, *n.*<sup>1</sup>
> ....
> *2. a.* The fibre of flax, hemp, or jute prepared for spinning by some process of scutching.

This 'tow' (still commonly appearing as part of the compound 'towheaded', that is, white-blond), is highly flammable, and as such the word was paired with 'fire' in now obsolete "allusive expressions ... as an example of two things that should not be brought into proximity" with the general meaning "to do or say something that may cause trouble, controversy, or upset" (*OED*, **fire** *n*, **P4b**).

Exegesis of Marthy's comment about Miss Tish ("She's all fire and toe, ain't she?") is, of course, not appropriate here; the general meaning, however, that Miss Tish is liable "to do or say something that may cause trouble, controversy, or upset", remains clear.

*OED* first attests the figure 'fire and tow' with a quote from a work by Chaucer composed around 1395, and the etymology of 'tow' (*n.*<sup>1</sup>, op. cit.) notes that the word is not known before the "last quarter of [the] 14th cent." I have not found any earlier instances. Widespread (but not common) use of the figure in fiction and newspaper reporting continues into the early 20th century.

Comment: Nearly all the historical examples occur in the context of cautionary allegories  concerning lust, seduction, or temptation. It's usage seems to have been confined to such matters outside Texas. From OED, which I was somehow able to look at this entry, from 1592 "This were to put fire to flaxe, and to offer soft bleeding harts as sacrifice to Cupids bowe and arrowes." *Fire to flax* being a variant of *fire to/and tow*. And here's a later example from a 1918 novel [*Running Sands*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/38753/38753-h/38753-h.htm#Page_106).

Comment: Getting closer in time and place - from the Hoosier Chronicles, 1858. ..."Ham, did you get the ring ? " "Yes," says I. "Oh, where is it? Give it to me." . " I havn't got it. I gave it back." She jumped to her feet like a tiger, and caught me by the shoulder, her eyes all-a-fire, and her voice hoarse, as she screamed out : " Ham Murdoch you mustn't trifle with me so much, if you do I'll kill you." I only laughed, though, and said : " Pshaw, woman, you are all fire and tow. I havn't got the ring now, but I'll get it in a day or two."

Comment: Above link - https://newspapers.library.in.gov/?a=d&d=LO18580227.1.4&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-------

Comment: This is the second reference from the right general time and place that uses the idiom in the sense of bluster that can't be backed up by action. The first one was a description of a military officer in Texas during the Texas - Mexico wars who was described as all fire and tow, meaning too eager to run to the fight. He was specifically said to possess no real training or sense of military strategies, and was contrasted to a companion who was a graduate of the Military Academy and regarded as a skilled officer. There is the sense that this idiom came to refer to a dog with more bark than bite.

Comment: Two contextual uses of the phrase should be enough to show that "all fire and tow/toe" = a large amount of trouble/discord: 1611 *Heer's a coyle to keep fire and tow a sunder.* T. Heywood, Golden Age -- 1890 *It is reckless to put fire and tow so close together.* News & Observer (Raleigh, North Carolina) fire, n. & int.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase is much older than I suspected:

[Change of Cheare, OR A Banquet of Jests.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FUpnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=Change%20of%20Cheare,%20OR%20A%20Banquet%20of%20Iests.&source=bl&ots=JqIKWSmK4L&sig=ACfU3U0tM-q_c3xWFbAe-k4VokPQwlgBkg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ4vjd3vLpAhUKTcAKHdDgAyMQ6AEwBHoECGUQAQ#v=onepage&q=fire%20and%20toe&f=false) (Anonymous 1634 fifth edition) p125

> "One seeing a fellow warming his feet by a hot Sea-coale fire: My friend saith he, what doe you mean to put Fire and Toe together."

and from "[***Matrimonial customs, or, The various ceremonies and divers ways of celebrating weddings practised amongst all the nations in the whole world done out of French.*** *The Third Treatise. Of Nuptial Rites, or Ceremonies, of Marriages practised amongst Ido∣laters and Pagans.](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A42526.0001.001/1:6?rgn=div1;view=fulltext)* by  Louis de Gaya. **(1687)**

> She also ordained that Women should go with naked Neck and Breasts, to the end that, exposing a Samplar of their Wares, they might the sooner allure Customers. The Men of that Country are very shy in their matching, and very fearful lest they should light upon a Crack-piece; for, to say the Truth, their Maids are generally all Fire and Toe.

From the above, and other sources, **to be all fire and toe**: seems to mean to be "hot-headed"; given to high emotion and dramatic action. Probably a reference to the torture of burning the feet and the agitated reaction that this caused.

Comment: I found the expression in ***No Quittin’ Sense***. After finishing it, reading your response, and considering the character “all fire and toe” is used to describe in that book, I’d say, yes, it means ‘hot-headed’. And more. It’s used for a person who tends to say forceful, judgmental things that cause discomfort. The kind of person, way back in the day, who would hold your feet to the fire.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered a newspaper reference to the expression in 1967. The Daily Banner,Greencastle, Putnam County, 15 March 1967 - Andrew (Old Hickory) Jackson was a man all fire-and-toe, a harsh and tireless soldier and politician, a circuit judge who demanded one time that a drunken rowdy come down from a tree or “by the eternal” a bullet would find his heart.

Answer (score 1):

"Fire and to[w]" is a warning against "sexual immorality," or more literally can be taken to mean "disaster."

It derives from an analogy in the Bible, specifically [Isaiah 1:29–31](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%201%3A29-31&version=KJV):

> 29 For they shall be ashamed of the oaks which ye have desired, and ye shall be confounded for the gardens that ye have chosen.
> 30 For ye shall be as an oak whose leaf fadeth, and as a garden that hath no water.
> 31 And the strong shall be as tow, and the maker of it as a spark, and they shall both burn together, and none shall quench them.

Isaiah dislikes the fact that Israeli pagans use oak trees to worship those he considers "false gods." The worshipping rituals may have included "sexual immorality," according to [biblical interpretation](https://www.bibleref.com/Isaiah/1/Isaiah-1-29.html). And thus he is comparing the pagans to hay, and their rituals will be the spark that burns them when God's judgement comes.

The first known use of this phrase, according to the other answers that cite *OED*, comes from a work from English poet Geoffrey Chaucer. That work is the proto-feminist *The Wife of Bath's Tale* (written between 1387–1400), in the part where the wife of Bath is quoting St. Paul advocating for virginity.

> Al were it good no womman for to touche,
> He mente, as in his bed or in
> his couche;
> [95] For peril is bothe fyr and tow t'assemble;
> Ye knowe
> what this ensample may resemble.

In Modern English:

> And though it were good to touch no woman's flesh,
>
> He meant, as in his bed or on his couch;
>
> For it is peril for fire and tow to assemble;
>
> You know what this example may resemble.

Or she might be referring to the *[Bal des Ardents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bal_des_Ardents)* accident in the French court in 1393, within the time period this work was written, where four people were killed by fire from a torch that lit their flax costumes ablaze.

I have not read the book you mentioned, but I think Marthy is probably trying to say "She's promiscuous." or "She's a recipe for disaster."

Comment: Farther into the man mentions a "tow sack", which is the same as a gunny sack.

Answer (score 0):

I could only find [this one written instance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all+fire+and+toe%22) - which can't be the same as that puzzling OP, since mine is spoken *by* a female, *of* a female. My guess is it's a (euphemistic?) alternative to ***all piss and vinegar*** (***full of beans***, lively, energetic, which Merriam-Webster euphemistically define as [*all **spit** and vinegar*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spit%20and%20vinegar)).

But unless anyone can show some convincing evidence to the contrary, I think so far as *origin* is concerned, it's a corruption / miscopying of [*all fire and **brimstone***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fire-and-brimstone#:~:text=phrase,full%20dictionary%20entry%20for%20brimstone). Here are a number of written instances of [*She's all fire and brimstone.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she%27s%20all%20fire%20and%20brimstone%22)

---

EDIT: Just found [this letter dated 1834...](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=c_leAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA210&dq=%22fire%20and%20toe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN1Ov9lfLpAhWRrHEKHcy0DJcQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22fire%20and%20toe%22&f=false)

> *[Some outraged local citizens] got up some letters **full of fire, and toe, and brimstone**, and bloody murder...*

...which arguably suggests the speaker there didn't think of ***toe*** and ***brimstone*** as being "the same word". But that doesn't mean they're not.

Comment: Samphire and mistletoe?

Comment: I'd have been quite prepared to accept that as yet another euphemistic alternative (except Google Books doesn't have a single recorded instance of those three words occurring together, let alone preceded by ***all*** and applied to a person! :)

Comment: The interesting part of your answer  is the finding of the expression "*She's all fire and toe, ain't she?“* which tells me that the expression does exist, however localized in time and space.

Comment: @user121863: I think that 1834 letter I found later is far more significant, because it specifically mentions both ***toe*** and ***brimstone***. I've no idea why I wrote ***mistletoe*** originally. (But I guess I'm bound to value that more highly, simply because it backs up my "armchair etymologist" ideas! :)

Comment: @user121863 'the expression does exist' is disingenuous. It implies a 'known and used' quantity which one Google hit fails to endorse. 'Colorless puce furiously sleeping ideologies' will probably register after today. But it's not an expression.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I agree it's a bit ott to say 'the expression does exist'. But we have found ***three*** written instances - all effectively for the same "variation on a theme" (and all likely to be considerably more durable than a comment on ELU!  :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -I am not from Texas or that par of America but I have the impression that it is or was used given that someone took the pain to put it down in writing.

Comment: @user121863: Don't assume *too* much! The fact that one or two people *wrote* it doesn't even prove that anyone ever actually *said* it. Sometimes writers either misremember (or never accurately heard) certain usage. Other times they'll deliberately write something they've never encountered before, simply because it "feels" like an appropriate "colloquialism" in some narrative context. Consider the kind of "invented slang" usages you might find in a sci-fi novel, for example, where sometimes we can be quite certain some expression we've just read doesn't "exist" (as past/present slang).

Comment: Much obliged for the heavy lifting. At this juncture, seems I should seek somebody who knows it by ear, not by eye. Gonna grab the phone and dial up East Texas. I'll report findings. Thanks again.

Comment: @FF Are you saying that 'dexitroboper' must be discounted?  Does lens-invention not count as word formation?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm not sure I'm saying *anything* here, apart from that I believe the ***toe*** in OP's example derives from ***brimstone*** (deliberately / knowingly or otherwise). I seriously doubt there's any real case for calling the cited usage ***an (established) "expression"***, but I didn't think I'd explicitly made that point anywhere above. As for the *Lensman* novels, I think I read them all as a teenager, but I doubt I've looked at one in the past 50 years.

Comment: @FF The lens throws out novel nouns, verbs etc to facilitate the discussion of non-Terran species, practices. Much like SF writers themselves, only Smith passes the buck.

Answer (score 0):

"all fire and tow" with little doubt refers on a literal level to the flame that leaps out when the wick of a candle catches fire before burning down to the point where the wax moderates the flame and it burns steadily.

So I suspect the figurative meaning is to be found in what it would mean to compare a person to that sudden and short-lived flare of flame: the person could be a gossip, or someone insubstantial, i.e.  who talks nonsense or who is all talk and no action, one whose words are "empty".

> Just like Dan's nonsense, all fire and tow. I s'pose he thought it would sound smart. I hope he split up a few kindlin's for his poor feeble old mother before he went. I see her when I come by yisterday hacking away in the wood house with a dull axe. I should think he'd be ashamed to go strutting round the way he does.
>
> "The Mate of the Daylight" by Sarah Orne Jewett (in *The Atlantic*, July 1882)

But David N. Mielke in  [*Teaching Mountain Children: Towards a Foundation of Understanding*](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED170090.pdf) (Appalachian Consortium, 1978) says "all fire and tow" refers to "A high-tempered person" (see pp. 18-19)
.

Comment: TimR, Many thanks for posting the best two sentences I'll read this month: "I hope he split up a few kindlin's for his poor feeble old mother before he went. I see her when I come by yisterday hacking away in the wood house with a dull axe." How did you find your way to them? Pray tell. And, yeah, thanks again.